# Do I need to use an insert or inner join?

Tags: mysql, join

I am working with MySQL version 5. I have two tables structured as shown below.

**Table1**

```
From     To     Time     TravelTime
```

**Table2**

```
From    To      Time     CongestionTime
```

I would like to achieve the following output.

If `From`, `To` and `Time` are equal in both the tables, then assign `TravelTime = CongestionTime`

*Table2* contains only a subset of the `From | To | Time` combinations available in *Table1*.

Comment: I am currently executing this query on a table of 35 mio items (table 1) and 1.6 mio items in table 2. I have a feeling this might take a long time to complete since it's very read intensive. Is there a way to generatie a unique key per `From/To/Time` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From is mysql reserved word. If you don't want to escape it, change column names "From" to "TimeFrom".

```
UPDATE table1,table2
SET table1.TravelTime=table2.CongestionTime
WHERE table1.From = table2.From
AND table1.To = table2.To
```

Comment: This answer did the trick..Thank you a lot Mr. Everest. I never thought of incorperating the second table in the [{UPDATE}] Statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Table1 Set Table1.TravelTime = Table2.CongestionTime
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.From = Table2.From
      AND Table1.To = Table2.To
      AND Table1.Time = Table2.Time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1
set traveltime = congestiontime
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.from = table2.from 
and table1.to = table2.to 
and table1.time = table2.time
```